# DP Approach ? Output should be the max sum. interview ( still have not idea, any hints) at at well known company

Tags: dynamic-programming

You have a table and in each cell there is either a positive integer or the cell is blocked. You have a player starting from bottom left and want to get to the top right in such a way that you maximize the sum of integers on your way. You are only allowed to move up or right but not through blocked cells. Output should be the max sum.

Comment: you may want to check out this video explaining what I think might be the same problem you're asking about: https://youtu.be/P8Xa2BitN3I?t=4m14s

Answer (score 0):

On my code I am making the assumption that the answer will fit on a long long type.
I am also assuming that is a square matrix for simplicity, but you can adapt the algorithm for any rectangular matrix with almost no effort. 
If the input matrix is N x N, the complexity of this approach is O(N ^ 2).

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

constexpr int maxDimension = 100;

using namespace std;

long long matrix[maxDimension][maxDimension];
long long dp[maxDimension][maxDimension];

int main()
{
    // I am assuming that the matrix is filled with positive
    // integers, and the blocked cell's are filled with -1.

    // reading the values for the matrix
    for(int i = 0; i < maxDimension; ++i) 
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < maxDimension; ++j) 
        {
            cin >> matrix[i][j];
        }
    }

    /*
        For every pair(i, j), 
        dp[i][j] is the maximum 
        sum we can achive going from
        (0,0) to (i, j)
    */

    // Observation if dp[i][j] is equal to -1, it is because we cannot reach the cell (i, j) because of blocked cells
    dp[0][0] = matrix[0][0];


    // this calculates the dp for row == 0
    for(int col = 1; col < maxDimension; ++col)
    {
        if(dp[0][col - 1] != -1 && matrix[0][col] != -1) 
        {
            dp[0][col] = dp[0][col-1] + matrix[0][col];
        }
        else dp[0][col] = -1;
    }

    // now I will calculate the dp for column == 0
    for(int row = 1; row < maxDimension; ++row) 
    {
        if(dp[row - 1][0] != -1 && matrix[row][0] != -1)
        {
            dp[row][0] = dp[row-1][0] + matrix[row][0];
        }
        else dp[row][0] = -1;
    }

    // Now that I have calculated the base cases, I will calculate the dp for the other states
    // I will use the following expression 
    /* dp[i][j] =  if (matrix[i][j] == -1)                        -> -1
                   else if (dp[i-1][j] != -1 or dp[i][j-1] != -1) -> max(dp[i-1][j], dp[i][j - 1]) + matrix[i][j]
                   else                                           -> -1
    */
    for(int row = 1; row < maxDimension; ++row)
    {
        for(int col = 1; col < maxDimension; ++col)
        {
            if(matrix[i][j] != -1 && ( dp[i-1][j] != -1 || dp[i][j-1] != -1) )
            {
                dp[i][j] = max(dp[i-1][j], dp[i][j-1]) + matrix[i][j];
            }
            else dp[i][j] = -1;
        }
    }

    if(dp[maxDimension-1][maxDimension-1] == -1) cout << "The top right cell is not reachable from the bottom left cell" << endl;
    else cout << "The best sum possible is " << dp[maxDimension - 1][maxDimension - 1] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```